# Unity ads showing only 3 or 4 times

Tags: unity-ads

I have published a game on googleplay that uses Unity rewarded ads. Once the player dies, they have an option of reviving by watching a rewarded ad. However when I try this, the ad shows only 3 or 4 times and then nothing happens after that(when I click the revive button). Here is the ad manager script:

```
string GooglePlay_ID = "123456";
bool test_mode = false;
string myPlacementId = "rewardedVideo";    

void Start()
{
   Advertisement.AddListener(this);
   Advertisement.Initialize(GooglePlay_ID, test_mode);
}

public void DisplayVideoAD()
{        
    Advertisement.Show(myPlacementId);
} 

public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult)
{

    if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished)
    {
      GameManager.instance.ReceiveReward();
    }
    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Skipped)
    {
        
    }

    else if (showResult == ShowResult.Failed)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("The ad did not finish due to an error.");
    }
}

 public void OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId)
{
   
    if (placementId == myPlacementId)
    {
        
    }
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string message)
{
    
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId)
{
    
}
```

Here is the ReceiveReward() function that's in the game manager. This function seems to work fine as after clicking the button, the game restarts with the score before the player died.

```
public void ReceiveReward()
{
    savedScore = (int)playerScore;
    UpdateUI(GameStates.Start);       
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong as the ads work a few times...Can someone please help?

Comment: Does your error function tell you anything about what went wrong?

Comment: @DMGregory   I don't get any errors....when I tested in the editor, I used the development mode and could the ads as many times as I wanted....However when I run the published app, the ads show only a few times...I think this could be because of the number of ads that can shown per hour/day...the number of ads also depend on the country....is there any way to check if the ad is available and if so then maybe I can disable the revive button before the game starts and once the ad becomes available then enable this button?